# LDA and pLSA packages (preferably for Python)

Tags: python, machine-learning

What packages for pLSA (Probabilistic Latent Semantic Analysis) and LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) do you recommend for Python? Java and C++ are OK too, but Python preferred.
Your experiences are highly appreciated.

There are many libs, so I don't know which to choose.

Answer (score 13):

[**Gensim**](http://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projekty/gensim/) seems to be most popular one. 
[It's on PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gensim) so, you can just install it using

```
sudo easy_install gensim
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Seems worth checking out. Although, on the first glance, it looks like it doesn't have pLSA (pLSI) - which I need, just LSA (LSI). Still, it's not mandatory for pLSA and LDA to be in the same package (although it is preferable).

Answer (score 1):

There's a good LDA example implementation in python that can be found here: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/topicmodeling.html and the tarball link is here: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/downloads/onlineldavb.tar

It's not a library, but rather an example implementation that automatically downloads wikipedia articles and runs LDA.  But I've found it to be extremely helpful as a reference for implementing my own LDA code.

Comment: Sadly the links are dead.