# PLSA implementation in Python

Tags: java, c++, python

Is their any library containing implementation of PLSA (Probabilistic Latent Semantic Analysis) algorithm ? Preferably in python, but Java/C++ is also welcomed...

Comment: Did you even google this? I found two likely hits as the first two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LDA and pLSA packages (preferably for Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897082/lda-and-plsa-packages-preferably-for-python)

Answer (score 0):

Mathieu Blondel contributed an implementation of PLSA that handles sparseness.

http://www.mblondel.org/journal/2010/06/13/lsa-and-plsa-in-python/